# My bash script is 29 line but there is an error in line 30

Tags: bash, syntax-error, git-bash

I'm new in bash, so I was practicing bash and there is an error in line 30. but my script is 29 lines.

The error is "`./goz.sh: line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file`"
what is my fault?

here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "What is your eye color's origin? \n"
echo -e "To learn, please enter; \n"
echo -e "For green 1\nfor brown 2\nfor blue 3 \nfor read 4"

while true
read -p  "pick a color please (for quit (q)):\n" goz

case $goz in
1) 
    echo "Mediterranean"
    ;;
2)
    echo "Asian"
    ;;
3)
    echo "Scandinavian"
    ;;
4)
    echo "Dark Lord of the sith"
    ;;
q  | Q)
    echo "quitting"
    break
    ;;
*)
    echo "You are never been existed."
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Use a tool like https://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix any shell errors.

Comment: See `help while` for correct syntax.

Comment: add "do" after while and "done" at end

Comment: Since the condition of a `while` loop can be an arbitrary *list* of commands, you need a special keyword to mark the boundary between the condition and the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `while` is

```
while [CONDITION]
do
  [COMMANDS]
done
```

so modifying the above code by adding `do` and `done` like below should fix the error.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Göz renginiz nereden geliyor? \n"
echo -e "Öğrenemek için lütfen: \n"
echo -e "Yeşil için 1'e\nkahverengi için 2'ye\nMavi için 3'e \nkırmızı için 4'e basınız."

while true
do
read -p  "lütfen bir renk seçiniz (çıkmak için 'q' ya basnız):\n" goz

case $goz in
1) 
    echo "akdeniz kökenli"
    ;;
2)
    echo "asya kökenli"
    ;;
3)
    echo "iskandinav kökenli"
    ;;
4)
    echo "dark lord of the sith"
    ;;
q  | Q)
    echo "çıkılıyor"
    break
    ;;
*)
    echo "Sen aslında yoğsun yoğ. hiç var olmadın, yoğsun."
    ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: thank you! your answer solve my problem.

Comment: I suggest to indent your code.